# Change default browser based on location?

Tags: mac, network, safari, geolocation

I use Chrome for work stuff and Safari for my personal stuff (each signed into my respective email). Is there a way to easily switch the default browser based on location? In the past I've used both ControlPlane and Sidekick for this - Sidekick is no longer available and ControlPlane hasn't been updated in years and crashes on a regular basis. Thanks for any suggestions. There is also Objectiv, but it also hasn't been updated in years.

Comment: I just have Chrome, Firefox and Safari in the dick and click on the one I want... Chrome for work, Firefox searching and Safari private... Works fine for me.

Comment: @SolarMike, that works well when I just want to browse the web. The problem comes when I want to open web files (e.g. .gdoc). If I double-click the file, it will open in the default web browser, which may or may not be the one that I want. For example, if Safari is my default browser and I open a work .gdoc, it will open in Safari where I'm signed into my personal account and won't open the file - I then have to change the default browser to get it to open in Chrome (where I'm signed in using my work account). Hope this makes sense.

Comment: For the odd file I need I copy / paste the link...

Comment: So, yes, I know how to do this also. Thing is, ControlPlane and Sidekick used to be able to change my default browser based on my wifi network - which was very handy (set it and forget it) and now that they are no longer being developed I miss this functionality. ControlPlane still works, but as it hasn't been updated in a long time it's getting a bit buggy (i.e. randomly crashes quite a bit). I might look elsewhere if no-one here knows how to achieve this.